# Checking is user author of number of posts?

Tags: posts, functions

I have this function...

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if (( in_category('Locked') ) && in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    /* Is subscriber, is in category Locked, has amount of posts */
    echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]');

} else if (( in_category('Locked') ) && in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    /* Is subscriber, is in category Locked, has NO amount of posts */
    echo '<div id="locked">
You are subscriber without number of posts!
</div>';

} else if ( in_category('Locked') ) {
    /* Is NOT subscriber, is in category Locked, has NO amount of posts */
    echo '<div id="locked">
Login or register pal!
</div>';

} else { 
    /* Is NOT subscriber, is NOT in category Locked, has NO amount of posts */
    echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]'); 
}
```

I need to apply "has amount of posts" or "check if user is author of numebr of posts" on first part of code...

```
if (( in_category('Locked') ) && in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) && ?????
```

If this way can't work, I would have one more possible solution, it is to auto move user from subscriber to contributor once subscriber posted number of posts, but this first solution would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [`count_user_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) is what you're looking for ;)

This is how you use it:

```
$user_post_count = count_user_posts( $userid , $post_type );
```

And it returns the number of published posts the user has written in this post type.

PS. And if you want some more advanced count, [`get_posts_by_author_sql`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts_by_author_sql) can come quite handy.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I put number of posts I want for the user to be able to see the content? For example I want user to add 5 posts before posts from category Locked become visible to him.

Answer (score 1):

Guy above answered correctly, but for anyone needing this further, I will add full code as response too...

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$user_post_count = count_user_posts( $user_ID );
$my_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'shortcode_name', true);


if (( in_category('Locked') ) && in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) && $user_post_count == 5 ) {
    /* Is subscriber, is in category Locked, has amount of posts */
    echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]');

} else if (( in_category('Locked') ) && in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    /* Is subscriber, is in category Locked, has NO amount of posts */
    echo '<div id="locked">
You are subscriber without number of posts!
</div>';
} else if (( in_category('Locked') ) && in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    /* Is subscriber, is in category Locked, has power */
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]'); 

} else if ( in_category('Locked') ) {
    /* Is NOT subscriber, is in category Locked, has NO amount of posts */
    echo '<div id="locked">
Login or register pal!
</div>';

} else if ( ! empty ( $my_post_meta ) ) { 
    /* Post meta exist */
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]'); 


} else { 

    /* Is NOT subscriber, is NOT in category Locked, has NO amount of posts */
    /* Post meta NOT exist */
    echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name_1]'); 
}
```